# Colors are not concatenating correctly in Sass

Tags: sass

I am trying to concatenate two colors in Sass:

```
$helloWorld: pink;
$secondString: red;

p {
  color:$helloWorld + $secondString;
}
```

But the result is:

```
 p {
  color: pink; }
```

Why aren't the colors concatenating to produce `pinkred`?

Comment: Did you read the SASS documentation on concatenation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Sass treats all colors as their hex value, regardless if they're named like `pink`. They're all hex values under the hood. Per the [Sass Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#colors):

> **Colors**
>
> *Any CSS color expression returns a SassScript Color value*. This includes [a large number of named colors](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/stable/lib/sass/script/value/color.rb#L28-L180) which are indistinguishable from unquoted strings.

The emphasis is mine. The documentation states that the color value is returned, which is the hex value. The included link also shows that named colors such as `pink` are just hex values under the hood. To address the adding issue, refer to the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#color_operations) again:

> **Color Operations**
>
> All arithmetic operations are supported for color values, where they work piecewise. This means that the operation is performed on the red, green, and blue components in turn. For example:
>
> ```
> p {
>   color: #010203 + #040506;
> }
> ```
>
> computes `01 + 04 = 05, 02 + 05 = 07, and 03 + 06 = 09`, and is compiled to:
>
> ```
> p {
>   color: #050709; }
> ```

The same principle applies here. When you use addition on colors, you aren't concatenating them like strings, so `pink + red` is not `pinkred`. Instead, the hex values are added piecewise. Here's an example:

```
$blue: blue;
$red: red;

p {
    color: $blue + $red
}
```

This yields:

```
p {
    color: magenta
}
```

From the example above, you can see that this does not perform string concatenation, but it's adding blue (`#0000FF`) and red (`#FF0000`) to create magenta (`#FF00FF`). In your case, pink (`#FFC0CB`) and red (`#FF0000`) are added piecewise to produce `#FFC0CB`, which is just pink. That's why you get `pink` instead of `pinkred`.

If you want to concatenate them like strings, *do not* use`+`. Instead, you can try [string interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) so the colors are treated as strings, not colors:

```
p {
    color: $helloWorld#{$secondString}
}
```

That will yield:

```
p {
    color: pinkred
}
```

You can also use a more verbose method so that it's forced to act like a string (unquote just gets rid of the quotes):

```
p {
    color: unquote($helloWorld+ "" + $secondString);
}
```

[Try it at SassMeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/2b484474f298f773ff465a513eccf066). Note that `pinkred` isn't a named colors in Sass.

Comment: Exactly! Perfect explanation +1